# Estimating epistemic uncertainty in object detection

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, bayesian, statistical-significance, object-detection

I've begun to explore a dataset wherein I am determining whether an object is **present**, after making N *attempted* indep. observations of the same object's **position**.

- While N attempts may be made, the **object may not be observed in certain attempts**; each observation is independent of each other and sequential observations confers no additional confidence.
- I am **determining presence from position**, which implies a degree of spatial **overlap** - that is, if I see the object in multiple observations overlapping the same location, then it gives me greater confidence I am truly observing this object.

An ad-hoc approach I have tried is to take the sum across all N observations, and threshold (ie. >= 5 / N frames has same position = object observed). However, I am striving to develop a **probabilistic model** to express the confidence of presence, given N observations of spatial position.

After browsing similar posts on CrossValidated, I realize this has similar flavours to the mean-shift algorithm. However, I am unsure how to (1) deal with missing observations (2) develop an a probablistic model for presence (since it's count-based, assume Poisson?) * The true distribution of observation is difficult to model due to limited data and noise.

Thank you for your feedback.

[image]